# Would a Bulgarian Bag help my conditioning or long-distance running?

Tags: running, conditioning

I am looking at different types of conditioning to boost my long-distance running speed and I've heard about the [Bulgarian Bag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_Bag) which aims to increase cardiovascular and muscular endurance while also adding to general conditioning.

Has anyone ever used one of these bags for a prolonged length of time and if so, would they recommend using them for conditioning work?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using them for a while now. I am really into functional fitness and use ketlebells, clubs, bodyweight exercises, etc. I bought a leather bulgarian bag from Escape Fitness for around £260. It is 22kg and was far too heavy for a first time user.

I also picked up a 12kg one from Dorset Kettlebells which is far better to use in terms of weight and cost, about £130 delivered. It is cheaper because it isn't leather but it makes no difference to be honest. Also try Wolverson for vinyl ones.

The exercises are fun and varied. I feel a real difference in my core strength and they give a fantastic conditioning workout. See YouTube for videos on how to use them. It is nice to have a bit of a change in your routine, and they create brutal explosive power and endurance in the legs which should translate well into your running. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've looked into buying one too and they are extremely expensive! I'll stick to using the one in my gym for the moment!